# ABP: Undefined background job for the job args type: A?

Tags: abp

I'm creating a background job and queued it successfully but when the job executing it throws this exception

```
    Volo.Abp.AbpException
Undefined background job for the job args type: Adva.BackgroundServices.GMVSendingToCRMArgs, Adva.BackgroundServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Volo.Abp.AbpException: Undefined background job for the job args type: Adva.BackgroundServices.GMVSendingToCRMArgs, Adva.BackgroundServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
   at Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.AbpBackgroundJobOptions.GetJob(Type argsType)
   at Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.Hangfire.HangfireJobExecutionAdapter`1.ExecuteAsync(TArgs args)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

And this is a sample of my code:
(1) Args class
[image: Args class]

(2) Background job:
[image: Background job]

(3) Background manager enqueue
[image: Background manager enqueue]

Comment: Have you followed the following documentations (just in case):
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Background-Jobs
& https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Background-Jobs-Hangfire. At the moment I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: Hi, this error is thrown once no get your job. Please check whether adding your values or not. If you have the correct job, you shouldn't get this error.
FYI.

Comment: @Kalves Yes, I followed the documentation. The problem is I'm creating the job and it is enqued successfully in Hangfire tables and I can see it in the enqueue tab in the dashboard but when processing it throws the error above. Also I wonder How the background manager know the job by the job args only as in the third image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed all the steps and logically it seems that nothing wrong, but I found that I used the wrong namespace `abp.BackgroundJobs` and I should use `Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs`.